# Proving that a sequence does not converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

I cannot figure out how to prove that the sequence $x_n\:=\:\left(-1\right)^n\:+\:\frac{1}{n}$ does not converge. I tried a proof by contradiction but the sequence ends up being $\frac{1}{n}+1\:-\:\frac{1}{n}$ and I don't know where to go from there. I also tried showing that its subsequences don't converge but I did not know what to do with them

$x_{2n} = (-1)^2n + \frac{1}{2n}$

$x_{2n-1} = (-1)^2n-1 + \frac{1}{2n}-1$

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1917113/42969

Answer (score 2):

Hint: \begin{align*}
(-1)^{2n} + \frac{1}{2n} &= 1 + \frac{1}{2n}  \\
(-1)^{2n+1} + \frac{1}{2n} &= -1 + \frac{1}{2n}
\end{align*}
For large enough $n$, one of these is greater than $1/2$ and the other is less than $-1/2$...